# How to implement "contain any" in flask/sqlalchemy?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The `contains` operation in SQLAlchemy only accepts one `Model` object instead of a list of objects. If I want to create a filter that accepts containing any of a group of objects, is there a more SQL-style way than creating multiple filters using contains and combining them with `union`?

For example, see the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class User(db.Model):
    id              = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name            = db.Column(db.String(100))
    son             = db.relationship('Son', backref = 'parent', lazy = 'dynamic')
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<"%s">' % self.name
class Son(db.Model):
    id              = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name            = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    user_id         = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<"%s">' % self.name

db.create_all()

son1 = Son(name = '1 a 1')
son2 = Son(name = '1 b 1')
son3 = Son(name = '1 c 1')
son4 = Son(name = '2 a 2')
son5 = Son(name = '2 b 2')
user0 = User(name = 'w1')
user1 = User(name = 'w2')
user2 = User(name = 'w3')
user0.son.append(son1)
user0.son.append(son2)
user1.son.append(son3)
user1.son.append(son4)
user2.son.append(son5)

db.session.add(son1)
db.session.add(son2)
db.session.add(son3)
db.session.add(son4)
db.session.add(son5)
db.session.add(user0)
db.session.add(user1)
db.session.add(user2)

db.session.commit()
son_query = Son.query.filter(Son.name.ilike('%a%'))
son_query_all = son_query.all()
print son_query.all()
user_query = User.query.filter(User.son.contains(son_query_all[0])).union(*[User.query.filter(User.son.contains(query)) for query in son_query_all[1:]])
print user_query.all()
```

The example firstly creates two models: `User` and `Son`, and then creates 3 `User` instances and 5 `Son` instances. `user0` contains `son1` and `son2`, `user1` contains `son3` and `son4`, and `user2` contains `son5`. Note that the name of `son1` and `son4` are both like `%a%`. Now I want to select all `User` instances containing `Son` instances whose name likes `%a%`.

The current method is to select all `Son` instances in `son_query_all`, and then selects `User` instances containing individual desired `Son` instances, and then combines the selecting result using `union`. Is there a more SQL-style way for SQLAlchemy to select the same? For example, is there anything like `contains_any` so that the last query can be changed into something like

```
user_query = User.query.filter(User.son.contains_any(son_query_all))
```

Note that of course I can define a custom `contains_any` function for the same purpose using the `union` and `contains` operation. My question is whether there is a more efficient way than simply `union` all `contains`-ed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to solve this kind of filtering is to use [`JOIN`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm). Basically you join `Son` table with `User` table and filter by joined entity's field.

In SQLAlchemy you can express it like this:

```
User.query.join(Son).filter(Son.name.ilike('%a%'))
```

And it will produce following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM user 
JOIN son ON user.id = son.user_id 
WHERE lower(son.name) LIKE lower('%a%')
```